# Is it possible to apply different Camera Settings to different NetStreams while publish one camera source with flash media server?

Tags: flash, camera, flash-media-server

I'm told that it's impossible to adjust FPS,video size and quality per the bitrate while **playing** a live stream, so is it possible to **publish** one camera source with different settings to different NetStreams in FMS?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible, based on first hand evidence:

- Each time you call `Camera.getCamera()` (the default cam in this case) you get a reference to the same camera object. So when you change the camera settings, they will be applied to all streams that are using the camera. Verified in a simple app.
- I've also seen that while my app is running and publishing the camera, that if I load another app (like the one at testwebcam.com), the other app's camera settings get applied to the camera in my app.